# How can I find the type of an element in kendo ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have dynamically created elements by using javascript. There are multiple types of elements (e.g. kendoComboBox, kendoTextBox, datePicker etc). I want to validate each element as per declaration when the user attempts to save the data.

```js
$.each(data, function(key, frmelements) {
            if (i <= 3) {
                //console.log(i);
                if (i == 1) {
                    frmString += '<div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left:0px">';
                }

                frmString += '<div class="col-md-4">';
                frmString += frmelements.property_name;
                frmString += ':<br />';
                if (frmelements.property_name == "PSS" && frmelements.property_type_id == 1) {
                    pss_value_id = '#prop_' + frmelements.propertyId + '_id';
                } else if (frmelements.property_name.includes("Style") && frmelements.property_type_id == 1) {
                    style_value_id = '#prop_' + frmelements.propertyId + '_id';
                }

                if (frmelements.property_type_id == 1) { //Text Box

                    var prop_value_id = 'prop_' + frmelements.propertyId + '_id';
                    var prop_value_name = 'prop_' + frmelements.propertyId + '_name';
                    // Check If numeric // Added by tanver instantly

                    if (fabricnumericText.includes(frmelements.property_name)) {
                        frmString += '<input style="width:80%" class="k-textbox" onblur="handleChange(this);" type="number" max="100" min="0" id="' + prop_value_id + '" name="' + prop_value_id + '_input">';
                        fabricids += "#" + prop_value_id + ",";
                    } else if (addFabricnumericText.includes(frmelements.property_name)) {
                        frmString += '<input style="width:80%" class="k-textbox" onblur="handleChange(this);" type="number" max="100" min="0" id="' + prop_value_id + '" name="' + prop_value_id + '_input">';
                        addFabricids += "#" + prop_value_id + ",";
                    } else {
                        frmString += '<input style="width:80%" class="k-textbox" type="text" id="' + prop_value_id + '" name="' + prop_value_id + '_input">';
                    }
                    // Check end 

                }
            }):
```

Comment: You could try `data()` and check if there is a known type in the returned list. See `$("#grid").data()` on https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index for an example.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use kendo validator. Check the demo here: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/index